# R Markdown formula not knitting

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am trying to put the following formula in my R markdown project:

[image]

My Latex code is the following:

```
$$min\limits_{f}(.)\left \{  \right\sum_{n}^{i=1} \left ( y^{_{i}}-f\left ( x_{i} \right ) \right )^2 + \lambda \int \left ( f''(x) \right )^2 dx\}$$
```

By somehow it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```
---
title: "asdf"
author: "asdf"
date: "29-1-2020"
output: html_document
---

$$min\limits_{f}(.)\left \{  \right\sum_{n}^{i=1} \left ( y^{_{i}}-f\left ( x_{i} \right ) \right )^2 + \lambda \int \left ( f''(x) \right )^2 dx\}$$
```

Comment: What do you mean by it "does not work"? Please post a [mre] together with the results or error messages you are getting.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to add R Markdown into the space above. What I mean by doesn't work is that it doesn't compile into equation format when I try to knit.

Comment: This is the error msg I get :  \[min\limits
                  _{f}(.)\left \{  \right\sum_{n}^{i=1} \left ( y^{_{i}}-f\l...

Error: Failed to compile rehab_22_01_2020.tex.

Comment: You can copy and paste a minimal R Markdown document. to format it as code, you can indent it with four spaces. this is best done by highlighting the code and hitting the `{}` button. And please [edit] your question to include error full messages. Best to include those for matted as code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the error messages one by one. When I process your code after replacing `html_document` with `pdf_document` I get:

```
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.
l.74 \[min\limits
                 _{f}(.)\left \{  \sum_{n}^{i=1} \left ( y^{x_{i}}-f\left ( ...
```

You are missing a `\` before `min` here.

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \sum@ 
l.70 \[\min\limits_{f}(.)\left \{  \right\sum
                                             _{n}^{i=1} \left ( y^{_{i}}-f\l...
```

`\right` has to be followed by a delimiter, e.g. `.`

Result:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

$$\min\limits_{f}(.)\left \{  \right.\sum_{n}^{i=1} \left ( y^{_{i}}-f\left ( x_{i} \right ) \right )^2 + \lambda \int \left ( f''(x) \right )^2 dx\}$$
```

[image]

However, I don't like the sizing of the curly braces and the `i` in the exponent. Why do you use `y^{_{i}}`? Should this read something like `y^{x_{i}}` or `y^{i}`? Taking the latter possibility and adjusting the braces I get

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

$$\min\limits_{f}(.)\left\{  \sum_{n}^{i=1} \left ( y^{i}-f\left ( x_{i} \right ) \right )^2 + \lambda \int \left ( f''(x) \right )^2 dx\right\}$$
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so basically a whole bunch of mistakes. I understand now.